# Expo ImageManipulator won't return desired result

Tags: react-native, expo, image-manipulation

I'm trying to use [Expo ImageManipulator](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/imagemanipulator) to resize an image selected from device.

The result I'm getting is a weird object like this, so it doesn't  work:

`{"_h": 0, "_i": 0, "_j": null, "_k": null}`

Why would it be so?

Here's my code:

```
...
import { manipulateAsync, SaveFormat } from "expo-image-manipulator";

const resizeImage = async (image) => {
    return await manipulateAsync(
      image.uri,
      [
        {
          resize: {
            width: 300,
          },
        },
      ],
      {
        format: SaveFormat.JPEG,
      }
    );
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `resizeImage` function is an `async` function. While calling this function you will either need to await (in a try-catch block) the function call or use `Promise Chaining`

1st Method:

```js
const yourFunction = async () => {
  try {
    const desiredResult = await resizeImage(yourImage);
    console.log(desiredResult);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
};
```

2nd Method:

```js
resizeImage(yourImage)
  .then(desiredResult => console.log(desiredResult))
  .catch(error => console.log(error));
```

Comment: Exactly, it was that... I have fixed it already but thanks for pointing out!

Comment: I think the `console.log(desiredResult)` need to change with `return desiredResult` ..?

Comment: You can customize the function as per your needs. This is just to show how async functions should be called. Glad you figured it out.